# How do I count the number of Facebook likes in articles?

Tags: views, 8, social-network

I am working on a Drupal 8 site. I added [fblikebutton](https://www.drupal.org/project/fblikebutton) to my articles to enable users to like content.

Is it possible to get the number of likes for each article as field? I am using the Views module to show the latest 3 articles, as in the following screenshot.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably setting the layout to **button_count** will do all the magic ;) 
This should be available in settings, or can be changed in MYTHEME_preprocess_fblikebutton.

Or use modules which provide this functionality, like:

- [social_counters](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_counters) and [shariff](https://www.drupal.org/project/shariff) have D8 versions.
- [views_fb_like](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fb_like) counts your likes. (D7 only yet)
- [facebookshare](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebookshare) implements this in combination with [social_stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_stats). (D7 only yet)

Comment: thank you for the answer , about the 2 modules you suggested are not available for D8 , but for your first recommandation can you please drop some tutorial links?

Comment: sorry - i missed the 8 - and added two with a D8 version. in the code of all these modules you find the API calls. for using the existing module have a look at fblikebutton.html.twig and it's preprocess function.